# fromtimestamp returns different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

I have the following code:

```
import datetime

dt = 1546955400
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt))
```

When I run this code on my local machine, I get the correct (expected) time which is

`2019-01-08 15:50:00`.

However I tried running this exact same code on a VM and the result was
 `2019-01-08 13:50:00` (two hours earlier). Why is this is happening and how can I fix it so that I always get the first one regardless of where the code is running?

Comment: You're seeing the *local* time based on that timestamp (which is for 13.50 UTC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` returns **local time**. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

> Return the local date and time corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by `time.time()`. If optional argument `tz` is `None` or not specified, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date and time, and the returned datetime object is naive.

The timestamp value is an offset in seconds from [the UNIX *epoch* value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number), midnight 1 January 1970, in the UTC timezone. The local time is a system-wide configured offset from UTC, the local timezone.

If your VM is producing unexpected results, you need to configure the timezone of the OS.

Alternatively, ignore timezones and only deal with time in the UTC timezone. For timestamps, that means using the [`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp).

Your specific timestamp is 13:50 UTC:

```
>>> dt = 1546955400
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dt)
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 8, 13, 50)
>>> print(_)
2019-01-08 13:50:00
```

so your VM is either set to the UTC or the GMT timezone (the latter is currently at UTC+0, until the switch to the UK [daylight saving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) timezone BST). Your local system is in a [UTC+2 timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B02:00), given your stated location from your profile that'd be [EEE, Easter European Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_European_Time).

Another option is to create a timezone-aware timestamp by passing in a `tz` argument. If you have a specific UTC offset, just create a [`datetime.timezone()` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone) for that offset:

```
utcplus2 = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=2))
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt, utcplus2)
```

However, it is usually better to store and operate on UTC `datetime` instances everywhere, and only convert to specific timezones when displaying information to users. This simplifies datetime handling as it lets you avoid a number of timezone corner cases and problems, such as mixing datetime information from different timezones and timezones with a summer and winter time distinction.

Comment: Is there something else I can use that isnt dependent on local time?

Comment: @ninesalt: yes, use the UTC timezone, so [`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp).

Comment: Wouldn't you then have to offset the result by 2 hours to get to 15:50?

Comment: You would use the UTC timestamp *everywhere*. Or specificy a timezone to translate the time to.

Comment: I would use UTC everywhere however I'm scraping local websites and storing the time/date so I'd have to convert the time on the website to UTC first.

Comment: @ninesalt: convert input data as soon as possible to a UTC format. Different sites will use different conventions to display time anyway, so you will always have a data cleaning task there.